# Windows 7 recent files integration for Visual Studio 2008

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2008

How do I get win7 to offer me recently opened solutions on the jumplist that appears when I click it on the startmenu.  I currently have a single source file showing on that list, and no idea why windows thinks that is it special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a registry hack to do this.

Save the below as a .reg file and import it to the registry.

Win64 version:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.Launcher.sln\Shell\Open\Command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Win32 version:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.Launcher.sln\Shell\Open\Command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Note that this will only add solutions to the MRU list when they’re opened, not capture the existing recent projects list in visual studio.